# gray buttons in ClearCase menu for Visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, clearcase

I'm using visual studio with clearcase integrated. I have several vs projects in CC. Most projects work fine with clearcase. But all the clearcase operations except Refresh are in gray color for some projects. That means, I can't do checkin or hijack in vs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the integration is complete and activated within your Visual Studio:
See "[ClearCase and Visual Studio 6.0 Integration Procedures](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133960)", in particular the registry value should be there:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SourceCodeControlProvider
ProviderRegKey:
Reg_SZ:  Software\Atria\ClearCase
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders=
ClearCase:  
Reg_SZ:  Software\Atria\ClearCase
```

The [technote swg21429258](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429258) mentions:

> One cause for this issue could be that the Visual Studio Solution has already been added to source control outside of Visual Studio.
>
> **Another cause could be that the Visual Studio Solution has not been copied into a ClearCase view and a ClearCase VOB in the 'right way'** (which is actually using the command line or Windows Explorer to copy).

Note: the latter is the most common cause: your project file (here a solution file) must be within a vob of a ClearCase View: if it is outside ClearCase, even though all the source files referenced by that solution file are in ClearCase, the ClearCase integration won't be active.

> - First you have to copy the solution to a ClearCase VOB outside of Visual Studio. Then you go back to Visual Studio and open the solution in a view, in the VOB and then add it to source control.
> - Use Windows Explorer or the command line (CLI) to copy the solution folder and all contents into a ClearCase view and ClearCase VOB.
>     Example: `\my_view\my_vob\my_solution_folder`
> - Do NOT add the solution to source control at this time.
>     Everything should exist as view private files and directories.
> - Start Visual Studio.
>     Choose Open Solution and browse to the view and VOB that contains the solution you just copied.
> - Open the `.sln` file.
>     If you receive a dialog box stating, The project location is not fully trusted, click OK to dismiss it.
> - In the VS.NET Solution Explorer, right-click on the Solution (highest node in tree) and select 'Add Solution to Source Control'.
> - You can also use this method to add an already worked on Solution to ClearCase source control.
>     However, if you have already attempted to manually add your solution to ClearCase source control in any other way, then you must first remove (rmelem) everything from ClearCase and start over using the above procedure.
>     The reason for this is that each type Solution in Visual Studio (and there are many types) has a different combination of files and directories - and some must be left outside source control as view private.

Comment: Thanks Vonc, it works now. After step:In the VS.NET Solution Explorer, right-click on the Solution (highest node in tree) and select 'Add Solution to Source Control'.